# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2 matrix not square

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i import with the code below from a .txt file a square matrix everything works perfectly. But when i change my matrix and make it not square i get the error message:

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

```
import numpy as np
import sys

c=[]
def matrixmod(path):

    with open(path) as f:
       for myline in f:
           c.append(myline.rstrip())

    for char in range(len(c)):
        c[char]=c[char].split()

    A=np.array([[None for _ in range(len(c))] for _ in range(len(c[0]))],dtype='float')
    for i in range(len(c)): 
        for j in range(len(c[0])):           
            A[i][j] = int(c[i][j])
    print(A)
```

This is my code and my error happens at the "A[i][j] = int(c[i][j])" line.

Comment: `for j in range(len(c[0])):` should probably be `len(c[i])`? If your rows can be of different lengths

Comment: I tried it and i get the same error

Comment: You'll have to change both locations where you use `len(c[0])`, not just the second one.

Comment: It finally worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `len(c[0])` for every iteration over `c`. This means that if each row can be a of a different size, you'll iterate outside of the bounds because of only using the size of the first row and not the row you're iterating over.

Change `len(c[0])` to `len(c[i])`, effectively using the size of the row you're iterating over instead of the length of the first row.

```
A=np.array([[None for _ in range(len(c))] for _ in range(len(c[i]))], dtype='float')

for i in range(len(c)): 
    for j in range(len(c[i])):           
        A[i][j] = int(c[i][j])
```